# XSendFile: Varnish + nginx reverse proxy + apache

Tags: apache, nginx, varnish, x-sendfile, x-accel-redirect

I have installed XSendFile on my server (using the `apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c`)

in vhosts I'v turned it on, and gave the directory of my files to it
now the problem is, ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

and this is the code:

```
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file_name");
header("X-Sendfile: $file_path_cmp");
```

I'm using CWP (`CentOS Web Panel`)

before I had apache only and it worked fine

now I have: `Varnish Cache (Port 80) -> Nginx Reverse Proxy (Port 81) -> Apache (Port 8181)`

everything works fine Except the downloading part.

Comment: What's in $file_path_cmp exactly, does it exist?